React Native - Sound Manager [Unable to resolve "../Utilities/Platform" from "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Image\AssetSourceResolver.js"]
I am trying to define a Sound Manager for my react-native app. I am new to all this as it's the first app I am creating.
I run my app using expo and I get an error saying
Unable to resolve "../Utilities/Platform" from "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Image\AssetSourceResolver.js"

I am not sure why this happens
The first code snippet is my SoundManager.js
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';

const soundFiles = {
  correct: require('../../assets/sounds/correct.mp3'),
  // Add more sound files here
};

const loadedSounds = {};

const loadSounds = () => {
  Object.keys(soundFiles).forEach((key) => {
    const sound = new Sound(soundFiles[key], Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(`Failed to load sound ${key}:`, error);
        return;
      }
      loadedSounds[key] = sound;
    });
  });
};

const playSound = (soundName) => {
  const sound = loadedSounds[soundName];
  if (sound) {
    sound.play();
  } else {
    console.log(`Sound ${soundName} is not loaded`);
  }
};

const stopSound = (soundName) => {
  const sound = loadedSounds[soundName];
  if (sound) {
    sound.stop();
  }
};

const unloadSound = (soundName) => {
  const sound = loadedSounds[soundName];
  if (sound) {
    sound.release();
    delete loadedSounds[soundName];
  }
};

export { loadSounds, playSound, stopSound, unloadSound };


I call this in my index.js file as you see below
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from '../components/i18n.js'; // Import the i18n configuration
import Home from '../components/Home/HomeScreen.js';
import Settings from '../components/Settings/SettingsScreen.js';
import SetUp from '../components/SetUp/SetUp.js';
import { loadSounds } from '../components/Sounds/SoundManager.js'; // Import the SoundManager


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    // Load all sounds when the app starts
    loadSounds();
  }, []);

  return (
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
          <Stack.Screen name="SetUp" component={SetUp} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
};

export default App;

and I then plan on mapping the sounds to the individual buttons on my screens using the handlePress I have for each button.
Does anyone know why I get this error? The app was working fine until I implemented this
